# Looking to make an opaque image/image caption in a teaser

Tags: media

I am interesting in making a teaser that just shows an image, which an opaque caption over it it saying blahblahblah READMORE and then a link to the page.

how would i do this?  i'm not even sure where to start.  i am using this with views kwick slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this in CSS using the content title and the opacity feature of CSS. See below (modify for your purpose)

```
.view-id-programmes.view-display-id-block_1 .views-field-title {
margin-left: 10px;
position: absolute;
background-color: 
white;
filter: alpha(opacity=68);
-khtml-opacity: 0.68;
-moz-opacity: 0.68;
opacity: 0.68;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-khtml-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks!!  going to try this now.  will this display on top of the image?

Comment: thats what the position absolute allowed

Comment: this is great, i always wndered abuot absolute, thank you